# Getting free apple certificate outside of xCode

Tags: ios, cordova, certificate

I am building an app using `phonegap`. Since im on `ubuntu` i have to build my app each time using build.phonegap.com.

Now i want to test my `application` on my `Iphone`. And here comes the problem. 
I need a certificate for it to build on IOS. So i went and created an account but quickly found out that i have to pay 99$ for the certificate.

Im not a professional app builder (yet) and all i want to do is to test my very unfinshed app.

Looking around the internet i found that i am able to get a certificate if i use xCode. However since i am on an `ubuntu` machine i am unable to download the program.

So my question is: is there another way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no. You NEED Xcode to build your app. Xcode now gives you one free certificate which you can use, but to distribute an app on the App Store you will need to pay the $99 (outside of using PhoneGap Build).